# Write permutation as disjoint cycles $(5 1 2)(3 1 2)(4 1 3)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, solution-verification, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

I'm really confused with permutations overall, I know the "algorithm" yet every time I get a mistake...

> Write this permutation in $S_6$ as disjoint cycles and find its order: $(5 1 2)(3 1 2)(4 1 3)$

**My try:**
$$\begin{pmatrix}  
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\
2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 6\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
so $(5 1 2)(3 1 2)(4 1 3)=(1 2 3 4 5)$.

Yet the solution in WolframAlpha states: $(1 4)(2 5)$ (order $2$ yet in my case the order is $5$). Am I mistaken?

Is there any good website for checking this sort of calculation (or is WolframAlpha actually correct)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

WolframAlpha evaluates permutations from left to right. Your calculation is correct when evaluating from right to left.

Comment: You don't say , Wow lol thank you very much!!

Comment: You're welcome, @Roach87.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you haven't accepted an answer yet, @Roach87; were you being sarcastic? Because I don't understand what warrants that reaction.

Answer (score 0):

I've been there. It takes a while to get used to working with permutations, and cycle notation isn't the easiest to work with. I would write out each cycle in 2-line notation:
$$ (512) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\end{pmatrix},
(312) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix},
(413) = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5& 6\end{pmatrix}
$$
To "multiply" these (what we are really doing is composing them), you can put them "on top of each other"

$$ \begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
$$

and then align the top row of the second permutation with the second row of the first one.

$$
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 4 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\\
2 & 5 & 3 & 4 & 1 & 6\\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
$$

and now do the same thing again:

$$
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix} \\
\begin{pmatrix}3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6 \\ 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6 \\
3 & 5 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 6 \\ 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 6 \end{pmatrix}
\end{matrix}
$$
which equals: $$
\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6\\ 4 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 6\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now that we have our permutation we can write it in cycle notation:[ 1->4, 4-> 1 ][ 2->5,5->2 ][ 3->3 ] gives (14)(25)(3). People normally drop the (3), so it can be written as (14)(25).

The order is 2 because if you compose the permutation (14)(25) with itself you get the identity.

Comment: The permutation is in $S_6$.